# Is there a way to do grouped checkboxes in Java?

Tags: java, checkbox

For example, selecting the parent checkbox will select all the child checkboxes (and vice versa if you unselect the parent checkbox).

If you unselect a child checkbox, the check mark in the parent checkbox will turn into a box.

If you unselect all the child checkboxes, the parent checkbox will unselect as well.

For example, something like this, but in Java.
[image]

Comment: You can do this easily by adding a listener to your continent checkboxes to automatically check the appropriate country checkboxes when the continent is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a true grouping of JCheckBox components, but it simulates a grouping and should outwardly display the behavior you've described. You could always implement your own grouped checkbox class, but I suspect my approach is more efficient.

```
// UI element declarations

JCheckBox cbAsia = new JCheckBox("Asia");
cbAsia.addItemListener(this);

JCheckBox cbChina = new JCheckBox("China");

JCheckBox cbIndia = new JCheckBox("India");

JCheckBox cbJapan = new JCheckBox("Japan");

JCheckBox cbPakistan = new JCheckBox("Pakistan");

JCheckBox cbThailand = new JCheckBox("Thailand");

JCheckBox cbVietnam = new JCheckBox("Vietnam");

// Item state handling loop

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

    if (source == cbAsia)
    {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            cbChina.setSelected(true);
            cbIndia.setSelected(true);
            cbJapan.setSelected(true);
            cbPakistan.setSelected(true);
            cbThailand.setSelected(true);
            cbVietnam.setSelected(true);
        }
        else
            cbChina.setSelected(false);
            cbIndia.setSelected(false);
            cbJapan.setSelected(false);
            cbPakistan.setSelected(false);
            cbThailand.setSelected(false);
            cbVietnam.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the "box" checkmark on the parent checkbox (Europe on the example above)?

Comment: cbAsia.setSelected(true). If you have additional inquiries, please post them in a new question to make finding specific answers easier for people who might see them in the future.